# Loop excel macro with a list in the code so user friendly

Tags: excel, vba, loops, format

I have written a macro in order to format 4 pivot charts as inverted colours upon opening the file. 
Works like a charm, however I need it to repeat this operation for each tab. 
There are as many tabs I want excluded as I want included. 
The other additional problem is that I want the report to be user friendly, 
If an additional tab is required later on then I want it to be easy for someone with little VBA knowledge to adjust and add the tab into the code with a few simple instructions. 
I was wondering if there was a way I could put in a list of tabs for the macro to apply to?

The code I have already is below:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
'
' Auto_Open Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+s
'
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    Selection.InvertIfNegative = True
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("L23").Select
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    Selection.InvertIfNegative = True
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("L23").Select
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    Selection.InvertIfNegative = True
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("L23").Select
'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 4").Activate
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
    Selection.InvertIfNegative = True
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 192, 0)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Solid
    End With
    With Selection.Format.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        .BackColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Range("L23").Select
```

Comment: If you add tabs, are they likely to be ones to include or exclude?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods.
**Without VBA:**
You can put in a particular cell (Es. A10) a "X" if you want to update, and nothing if you don't want. Update the code like:

```
For Each Sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sht.Select
    If Sht.Range("A10").Value = "X" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
        ...
        Range("L23").Select
    End If
Next
```

**With VBA:**
Adding a simple Array with the name of the Sheets to be updated. Modify the code:

```
Dim Sht(1 To 10) As String
Sht(1) = "Sheet1"
Sht(2) = "Sheet3"
For e = 1 To UBound(Sht)
    If Sht(e) = "" Then Exit For
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sht(e)).Select
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Activate
    ...
    Range("L23").Select
Next
```